# Swift array behaviour

Tags: arrays, swift, ios8

In Swift arrays have a special behaviour, but why here does arr1 contain two times "item 1" whereas arr2 contains it only once ?

What does defining arr1 as an instance variable change here (versus defining arr2 as a local variable) ?

Update: I'm using Xcode 6.0.1

[image]

Comment: Yup. I got the same result in Xcode Version 6.0.1 (6A317) :| I got to say it's a bug?

Comment: @ytbryan I'm using the same Xcode version as you.

Comment: yah. Looks like your best bet is to make it a local variable. Referring to PartiallyInifinite answer.

Or use the Xcode GM.

Comment: I guess I will use the 6.1 GM, I don't really find that the local variable trick is a good bet :-) Arrays or Classes or I don't know what seem broken, I'd rather use a working version

Comment: yeah. sounds like a right choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can reproduce this result reliably in Xcode 6.0.1:

[image: Xcode 6.0.1]

But not in Xcode 6.1 GM:

[image: Xcode 6.1]

Looks like it's a bug that got fixed.

As a temporary workaround, this works in Xcode 6.0.1:

[image: Workaround]

Comment: Ok, so I'm not the only one :-) thank you guys, Swift and Xcode bugs are driving me crazy...

Comment: @thomas.g I gave up trying to use it around the time I tried to use objc APIs that needed method selectors, right after giving up on the impossible to decipher initialiser overriding rules. Personally, I don't think it's worth the pain of the constant bugs, unnecessary and nonsensical restrictions, and sometimes unwieldy/unclear syntax, just to get the ~1.5x performance improvement over objc, which gives you the full power of performance of C whenever you need it.

Comment: I'm starting to feel the same. But soon I have to give a training on iOS development with Swift so no choice... but I must say that I'm a bit anxious ;-) At least for me Xcode / Playgrounds seems to crash less often since it isn't a beta anymore...

Comment: @thomas.g it seems ok until you try to do something serious in it; I tried to write a today widget for my timetable app in it, and it felt like it was actively putting up barriers before my to prevent me from writing a program that did what I wanted. Gave up and rewrote in objc, ~2x shorter code, and actually works.